# Has anyone hit the wrong color ball in an important snooker match?

Tags: snooker

I have been watching snooker for a few months now and I have never seen a player hit the wrong type of ball. Personally, I often get confused and forget which type the player is on (color or red) and then am surprised when the player lines up on the opposite type of ball.

Has any top player ever hit the wrong type of ball deliberately in an important match? By "hit the wrong type", I mean that the player deliberately pocketed a red instead of a color, or vice versa.

Comment: I added "deliberately" into your last paragraph because players have often accidently done this. If you meant to include those cases, please revert - although I'd then be very tempted to close it as "too broad".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because colour-blind players can easily mistake the brown for a red. Usually when the brown goes down table amongst the reds. Peter Ebdon and Mark Williams have hit the brown by mistake on TV.

You're not allowed to ask the ref where the brown is, or what colour a ball is. You can only ask "Is that the brown?". If anyone knows the rationale for such pedantry in the rules, I'd love to understand it.